# How to extract a part of DataFrame using first and last row python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm creating a new DataFrame from another DataFrame.
I have the first and last row in a different variables each one. What do I need to extract this rows to create a new DataFrame?

1. I already checked the variables are right but when I created the new DataFrame and used .describe() but then the DataFrame is empty.
2. I tried replacing the variables for the actual dates and in this case one of the statistics is wrong because the output for first is wrong.

## FIRST TRY

```
corrected_log = git_log.loc['first_commit_timestamp':'last_commit_timestamp', : ]

print(corrected_log.describe())
```

> OUTPUT

```
                  timestamp               author
count                 0                     0

unique                0                     0
```

## SECOND TRY

```
corrected_log = git_log.loc['2005-04-16 22:20:36':'2019-04-05 05:07:45', : ]
```

> OUTPUT

```
                                   timestamp                   author

count                                  1400                      1400

unique                                 1357                       393

top                         2014-12-11 23:56:04          Benjamin Romer

freq                                    15                         46

first                       2013-10-02 14:56:14                    NaN

last                        2015-08-01 10:03:00                    NaN
```

What I expected the output of first date `'2005-04-16 22:20:36'` but the actual output is `'2013-10-02 14:56:14'`. It seems that the first row is wrong in the new DataFrame.

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: it must be `git_log.loc[first_commit_timestamp:last_commit_timestamp, : ]` (i.e. without quotes) instead of `git_log.loc['first_commit_timestamp':'last_commit_timestamp', : ]`

Comment: also you'll have to check your data types: right now it looks like your timestamp column is of `str` type, but you'll probably want to have a datetime type column (see [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for conversion)

Comment: Just tested data types for 'first_commit_timestamp' and 'last_commit_timestamp' and this is the answer <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>. There must be something obvious... Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Stef I also tried without quotes git_log.loc['first_commit_timestamp':'last_commit_timestamp', : ] but this is what appeared:  KeyError: Timestamp('2005-04-16 22:20:36')

Comment: this tell us that the given Timespamp('2005-04-16 22:20:36') is not in your index. Without some concrete example data it is almost impossible to give you a working solution, see @Trenton_M's comment above.

Comment: @Stef Thank you!! I think that you're right. Maybe the problem is not in this part of the code. This is the first time that I ask a question and this is my first project. You really help me. I'll try again and maybe ask later but with more info.